# Image getting cropped rather than resize

Tags: html, css, image

I want to resize an image, but actually is it getting cropped! why?

**html**

```
<div class='data_block'>
    <img src='https://www.blueskyexhibits.com/website/wp-content/uploads/sky-home.jpg' class='data_image'/>
     <div class='data_title'><p>
     <a href='article/".$row['ar_id']."'>gdfgdfgdfggdf</a></p>
     </div>
     <div class='data_desc'>
    <p>dfgdfgdfgdf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.data_image {   width: 250px;   height:200px;   border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; }
```

Rest of the css necessary code, you will find it here:

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqjwaxe3/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set height to auto then it doesn't get cropped, but it throws the description out a little so you have to adjust the margin tops. I adjusted them to 18% and 15% Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqjwaxe3/1/)

```css
.data_block {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  width: 670px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}
.data_image {
  width: 250px;
  height:auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
.data_title a
{
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  font-weight: 600;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: right;
  margin-top:-19%;
  width:450px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#2E84C2;
}


.data_title:hover a
{
 color: #272727;
}

.data_desc {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  text-align: center;
  width:450px;
  float:right;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-top: -15%;

}
```

```html
<div class='data_block'>
 <img src='https://www.blueskyexhibits.com/website/wp-content/uploads/sky-home.jpg' class='data_image'/>
   <div class='data_title'><p>
     <a href='article/".$row['ar_id']."'>gdfgdfgdfggdf</a></p>
   </div>
   <div class='data_desc'>
    <p>dfgdfgdfgdf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is give the width to the parent div and give max-with property to the child i.e.image tag.

//parent div css

```
.data_block {
  width: 250px;
}
```

//child img tag css

```
.data_image {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

This please modify the css that i have written here and try.

I am 100% it will adjust the whole image inside the parent div without affecting the aspect ratio of the image and get resized without being cropped.

## happy sunday. :)

Comment: no! the data block is suppose to be 670px ... it shouldn't be 250px!

Comment: okay you can keep that 670px and add a child div next to it and give it 250px width i.e. add a div that is child of data-block div and make img tag the child of this new div and give this new div width:270px.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this might help!

```css
.data_image {   width: auto;   height:100%;   border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; }
```